# How do you create a SQL Where Clause using fields in a dynamic query?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

This is a small sample of a larger query I am trying to run. It is a dynamic query so I put the entire thing into a string and then execute it. However, it is failing. The user sends in just the month and year. I then execute it. But it is telling me the fields can not be bound.

```
declare @sqlstr varchar(5000)
set @sqlstr = 'SELECT     FirstName, LastName FROM  MyTable Where '
set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + CONVERT(varchar(2), MyTable.MyDateMonth) + '/1/' + CONVERT(varchar(4), MyTable.MyDateYear)
set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + ' = ''8/1/2006'''

exec(@sqlstr)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing some quotes around the CONVERTs

```
set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + 'CONVERT(varchar(2), MyTable.MyDateMonth) + ''/1/'' + CONVERT(varchar(4), MyTable.MyDateYear)'
```

Adding print @sqlstr can help you debug this.

Also you're exposing yourself to a [SQL injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx) so you should [sp_ExceuteSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) instead of just exec

Comment: Actually you should quote the entire expression that builds the date, like this: `... + 'CONVERT(varchar(2), MyTable.MyDateMonth) + ''/1/'' + CONVERT(varchar(4), MyTable.MyDateYear)'`.